# Time space trade-off

Tags: java, math, if-statement, for-loop

I was asked on a quiz the following question and had NO idea what to ask my self when prompted to design a more efficient segment of code. I mean I know if-else are time consuming, I was thinking maybe a for loop? I was curious if someone could A. tell me if there is only 1 answer and B. walk me through why what ever the solution may be runs so much faster.

It says: Suppose the following segment of code is very time consuming, write a segment that shaves at least 2 minutes of the run time.

```
if (f(n)%==0)
  key = 3*f(n)+4*f(n)+7;
else 
  key = 6*f(n)*f(n)-33;
```

Comment: @Bathsheba and then the code breaks, because it relies on some undocumented side-effect of `f` :P

Comment: @resueman - Well. Actually pre-computing makes sense here. Unless you are telling me that f(n) changes. I don't think it does. since n is not changing, f(n) should be consistent for a given "n".

Comment: @TheLostMind "f(n) should be consistent for a given 'n'" - Yes it should. That doesn't mean it will be. I assume precomputing is the expected answer, but I think it's a poor question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the quiz, the optimized code segment will shave at least two minutes of time as a result. You can deduce that the given code segment takes at least two minutes to calculate.

Regardless to the results of the conditional, if statement, you are calling `f(n)` 3 times in the given code segment.

By calculating `f(n)` once at the beginning and assigning the value to a variable to be used in subsequent calculations...

Something like this:

```
result = f(n)
if (result%==0)
   key = 3*result+4*result+7;
else 
   key = 6*result*result-33;
```

... you will **reduce** the **time of execution** by (**2** x **execution time of** `f(n)` **call**) - (**execution time of declaring a variable and assigning a value to it** + ( **2** x **execution time of reading value from that variabl**). The execution time of declaring and assigning a value, reading the value from that variable, and the other statements in the given code (like the if statement and logical expression operations) is insignificant (probably less than 1 millisecond).

In accordance to the expected result, you can deduce that each call to `f(n)` is taking at least 1 min to execute; to re-iterate, the difference in time between the given code segement execution yield, and the now optimized code segment execution yeild, as a result, is 2 minutes.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the first deduction of the give code segment execution time **being more than 2 minutes** is what I think Jadiel was alluding to; However, that deduction is appended to with the subsuequent considerations; Since each call is a least 1 minute.. the given code segment execution time will be at least 3 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

"I mean I know if-else are time consuming, I was thinking maybe a for loop" this is not correct. Consider what's happening here that's *actually* time consuming. Hint: `f(n)` could be doing many things. But if the code takes a long time to process, your only best bet is that `f(n)` is the culprit. The only other thing happening here is an `if-statement` which is fast, and some arithmetic (which computers are pretty darn fast at).

Luckily, you are calculating `f(n)` for a fixed input `n` multiple times! Save yourself the trouble by saving the output of this method in a variable then just using the variable. I don't know where you or your teacher got "2 minutes" from, that's arbitrary nonsense in my opinion.

Comment: Okay, so this method should be run while it is less than "n"?

Comment: Extra emphasis on 1. the first point: "if-else are time consuming" is only true relative to other code that never does any memory access (cache miss), synchronisation (locking), or branching. And 2. assuming `f(n)` is the issue is a guess (OK, in this case hard to see anything else – no overloading of operations in Java), and one should *profile* and not guess.

Comment: @Jengo You comment makes no sense: there is only one `n` and it never changes.

Comment: @Kon but isn't the output being saved in "key"

Comment: @Jengo You are computing some value `f(n)`, in some method `f`. Presumably `f` is deterministic and non-random (since this seems like a class quiz that's likely the case), then for multiple iterations you have `f(n) == f(n) == f(n)`. So you don't need to compute this value multiple times. Compute it once, store it in a variable, then just use that variable.

Comment: As resueman said, what if f(n) has side effects? Then this obviously won't work. I for myself don't really have an answer for this. Using the `?:` operator might cause the assembler to generate conditonal move instructions, but that's not really a solid answer,

Comment: @Beko in the context of a quiz issued to a student who is clearly still learning programming fundamentals, I think it's safe to assume an ideal `f` with no side effects, consistent returns (`f(x) == f(x)` always), and a long running time. No other context is given so these assumptions are reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

The thing to note is that `f(n)` gets called 3 times in all cases.  If we are assuming that is the bottleneck, then we want to minimize the number of times we call that function.

Note, too, that the result of f(n) is a constant (assuming no external factors).  Therefore, you only need to calculate it once.

Comment: Why would it get called 3 times no matter what, I'm so lost.

Comment: Step through the code slowly.  That may help.  It may also help to replace `f(n)` with something that seems more "normal" (if you're a Java person).  Something like "`getInt(n)`".  Just a hint.

Answer (score 0):

If your professor says that you need to shave two minutes from the code, then you can say that the code takes at least two minutes to calculate.  You are calculating `f(n)` 3 times in the code, then it is a safe bet to say that each `f(n)` calculation takes around 40 seconds, assuming no cache.  Then, by calculating `f(n)` once at the beginning and saving the result to use it in the other four calls will save you `40*2` seconds.

Something like this:

```
result = f(n)
if (result%==0)
   key = 3*result+4*result+7;
else 
   key = 6*result*result-33;
```

Comment: There is a lot of things wrong here. He never said it takes 2 minutes, he said he needs to shave off 2 minutes. Also, the `f(n)` call happens at most 3 times, not 5 times. The math therefore is completely off. This shouldn't be the accepted answer just because you wrote his code for him.

Comment: @Jadiel Would I calculate F(N) right before my if statement?

Comment: @Jadiel the thing that makes no since to me is the calculation DEPENDS on if the remainder is 0 so how could I possibly calculate it prior

Comment: @Jengo No, the result of `f(n)` does NOT depend on the mod function.

Comment: @Kon. I have fixed the issues of the number of times f(n) is calculated in the code. About the comment that the code takes 2 minutes: If the professor says that you need to shave 2 minutes from running the code, then you can assume that the code takes at least 2 minutes to execute.

Comment: See thats how I originally wrote my solution and I erased it because I thought it was incorrect -.- or I guess my solution would not matter very much. that sucks.

Comment: @JadieldeArmas, My assumption would be that `f(n)` takes 1min +, since the result is you're reducing this procedure by 2 function calls.. this is presuming the compiler is going to optimize the results of the 2nd func call in the same execution line in the first place.. I'm not sure why you're including the first call to `f(n)` in your calculations.. that call is still going to be made - to assign the value to a variable... the difference in time is what is relevant here..

Comment: correction to the above: **this is presuming the compiler [isn't] going to optimize the results...**